# Filter the sidebar in VS Code to only show certain folders

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-editor

I find myself in a situation where let's say I'm working on something to do with `Cats`, and I want the siderbar of Vs code (where it lists a directory of folder/files in my project), but filtered to only include folders with the word `Cats` in them. This wouldn't be my entire project, just a few folders to do with `Cats`, so I can focus more easily. Is there such a thing like this in the form of an extension, it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are using the latest version of Vs Code.
Tap with your mouse on the directory sidebar. Then start typing. A small search window will appear. Then hover over the search window and press the appearing button. (the three thin stripes). Vs Code will then filter on your search. [image]